# How can I find the condition of all the stable and unstable equilibrium solutions of $y'=\sin(4y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Question: Find under what conditions of $n$ is $y=n\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$ stable or unstable given $y'=\sin(4y)$.

I actually have the solutions given by my lecturer, but there are still few things that I am unclear about.

His solutions:

> Take $n$ to be even ($2m$) . Then $y\:=\:\frac{2m\pi }{4}=\frac{m\pi }{2}$
>
> If $\frac{m\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}<y<\frac{m\pi}{2}$
>
> $2m\pi -\pi <4y<2m\pi $
>
> $y'=\sin(4y)<0$

My question is how did he arrive at this inequality? and why did he minus $\frac{\pi }{4}$?

And he also did:

> $\frac{m\pi }{2}<y<\frac{m\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}$
>
> $2m\pi < 4y < 2m\pi + \pi $
>
> $y'  = \sin(4y) > 0 $

Also how did he arrive at this inequality and why did he add $\frac{\pi }{4}$?

What about the odd numbers? He has done nothing about the odd numbers.

Comment: Use `\sin` for $\sin$ and do not add whitespace unnecessarily to your $\rm\LaTeX$. $\rm\LaTeX$ is very good about adding whitespace automatically to equations to make them look nice.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1, (that you already solved) was to find all the equilibrium points, that is where $y' = 0$. This is at $y = n \frac{\pi}{4}$ for all integers $n$.

At all other $y \in \mathbb{R}$, either $y' > 0$ or $y' < 0$.

An equilibrium point $y = n \frac{\pi}{4}$ is stable if the region "above" it is $y' < 0$ and the region "below" it is $y' > 0$.

Your prof has shown for any even $n = 2m$, $y = m \frac{\pi}{2}$ is unstable because the region "above", namely $(m \frac{\pi}{2}, m \frac{\pi}{2}+ \frac{\pi}{4})$, satisfies $y' > 0$, and the region "below", namely $(m \frac{\pi}{2}- \frac{\pi}{4},m \frac{\pi}{2})$, satisfies $y' < 0$.

The add/subtract $\frac{\pi}{4}$ come from that's how far to the next equilibrium point.

The odds are the stable ones. See if you can work out why.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the answer. Why did he add $\frac{\pi}{4}$, can you explain that further? How do you know the next equilibrium point is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ away?

Comment: The eq points are $y = n \frac{\pi}{4}$. So there's an eq point every $\frac{\pi}{4}$